# How to i change focus node from dropdown to textfield with RawKeyboardListener as it listen twice to key press in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I tried to use RawKeyboardListener to achieve this.
as it listens twice to rawkeyupevent & rawkeydownevent. I only use one of it
but I face two problem

1. when I change focus to dropdown by pressing enter from the text field before it. the RawKeyboardListener in that dropdown listens to the function that change focus to next focus node. that's why it skips dropdown & jumps to next focus node.
2. when I try to request focus node to the newly added field from dropdown with RawKeyboardListener that added by pressing enter, the focus node is not changing.

I tried to search on the internet for 3 days but I can't able to find a solution. please help me with this

[Code of RawKeyboardListener Func in dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTMfr.png)

[Code of RawKeyboardListener Func in dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqzD8.png)

[Text Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl5T0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use FocusScopeNode to listen to the event.

```
final FocusScopeNode _focusScopeNode = FocusScopeNode();
```

assign this `FocusScopeNode` to the widget where you actually want the event to be called.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.